# AWS EC2 pay per hour with 100% availability

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to run an  server for an application I have.

I'm a complete beginner with AWS, so bear with me.

There will be about 50 users (all from the same time zone) that will be accessing the server and I would like to have near 100% availability.

The application I have requires 2 processors and 2GB ram.

I could pay for a machine 24/7 or even only 18 hours a day, assuming I turn it off at night, but I there will be some days where the server is not used at all.

I was wondering if the following is possible: when amazon detects that someone is requesting something from my server, it turns it on in real time, and then forwards the request to my server. After say 5 minutes of no activity, it will turn my server off. This way I can only pay for hours when there is traffic.

Is this possible?
How have people solved similar problems?

Comment: You're aware of the "reserved instance" pricing, yes?  A lot of AWS newbies miss the fact you can pay for 1-3 years up-front and (amortized) get a serious discount on the regular "on demand" pricing.  I suspect if I was you and wanted to save money on AWS I'd be more inclined to figure out how to get it to fit onto a t2.small or even t2.nano instance (or implement it with purely Lambda and DynamoDB/S3, even) than try to figure out complicated schemes bringing a machine up on demand.

Comment: I don't have that option. I didn't develop the application, the requirements are from the vendor. But yes I'm aware of the reserved option. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No this isn't possible. There is nothing built into AWS to detect traffic and start an EC2 server like you suggest. Plus the startup time on an EC2 server is at least a couple minutes, so those first incoming requests would have to wait a really long time.

You might want to look into running multiple small servers instead of a single larger server. AWS does have the ability to balance the load across multiple servers and add/remove servers from the pool based on traffic. You could have as few as one server running when there is no traffic, and have more servers automatically created as load increases. Look into the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) service for this.

If you want to run a truly "serverless" environment where you only pay for compute cycles in milliseconds, instead of servers by the hour, you could look into using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). If you can architect your system to run on Lambda you are almost guaranteed to save costs, but it can be a real challenge to convert an existing system to this sort of architecture.

If you want to look outside AWS you might find something more along the lines of what you describe with [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs). Heroku's [free tier](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) also works similarly to your description, but as soon as you outgrow the free tier you have to upgrade to always-running instances.